# How to get the price your market order was filled at using IBapi?

Tags: python, ib-api

I'm working on a test algorithm using IBapi with python (IBKR native API).
How can I get the prices my market orders were filled at?
I looked into the [official documentation](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/open_orders.html) but it was hard to understand.

I would be so grateful if you could help me.

Comment: I doubt if it is something suitable to stackoverflow, which is more to deal with technical questions.  Anyway, with a quick glance, I think what you need to look into is Execution.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is related to business knowledge instead of a technical question which Stackoverflow aimed for

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I'll do what you suggested.

Comment: By the way, the help I was looking for is the right "code" to give the API so it is suitable to post in Stackoverflow I think.

Answer (score 3):

This is partial code but implement these callbacks in your wrapper impl.

```
def execDetails(self, reqId: int, contract: Contract, execution: Execution):
    print("ExecDetails. ReqId:", reqId, "Symbol:", contract.symbol, "SecType:", 
           contract.secType, "Currency:", contract.currency, execution)
```

If you look up the Execution class you'll see a field for price along with some others.

You should also impl

```
def orderStatus(self, orderId: OrderId, status: str, filled: float,
                remaining: float, avgFillPrice: float, permId: int,
                parentId: int, lastFillPrice: float, clientId: int,
                whyHeld: str, mktCapPrice: float):
```

Which will be called may times depending on the order and the avgFIllPrice will be current.

Comment: Thank you so so much, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Is it possible to use for example "execution.price" as a variable and plug it in functions later in the code?
**sorry if my questions are stupid but I'm just new to all this

Comment: @Elias execution is a class and price is a field, look at the docs and source code.  Maybe do some python tutorials first.  I haven't seen your code but normally your wrapper class will have fields and one could be assigned to like `self.price = execution.price` for just the price.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you so much again for the help.
I appreciate it